# Cannot switch branch because of "phantom" file

Tags: node.js, git, path, git-checkout

> OS: Windows 10

I have a script that writes files into a folder. The script contained a mistake when I ran it for the first time.

```
var store_path = path.join(__dirname+ '../fabric-server/config/admin')
```

Instead of

```
var store_path = path.join(__dirname, '../fabric-server/config/admin')
```

Here is a partial view of the directory:

```
+---fabric-server
+---fabric-setup
+---fabric-setup..   < Should not be there
```

The script was executed from `fabric-setup` and should write into `fabric-server/config/admin`. However, due to the error, it somehow created `fabric-setup..`. Surprisingly, `fabric-setup..` contains the exact same content `fabric-setup` has.

Unfortunately, I fixed the script, executed it again, commited and pushed without removing the `fabric-setup..` folder. And of course, it creates problems.

---

**Local copy of the project**

On my local machine, I have:

```
+---fabric-server
+---fabric-setup
+---fabric-setup..
```

fabric-setup is OK.
fabric-server is OK.
`fabric-setup..` should not be here and contains the same as `fabric-setup`. **It does not contain `fabric-server/config/admin`**

When deleting the `fabric-setup..` folder from Explorer, it deletes `fabric-setup`. When trying to delete again `fabric-setup..`, it tells me it is not here anymore.

---

**Remote copy of the project**

[image]

---

**Cloning the project**

When cloning the project, I cannot switch to the branch that contains this `fabric-setup..` folder. It gives me the following error:

[image]

And many files suddenly get into untracked state for no reason.

Can someone explain me what the hell is going on and how can I fix this?

Edit: Yes I could checkout previous commit. But still. This problem is weird.

Comment: Are you working on both mac and windows? Files/Directories that end with a dot would cause such a problem on windows. If `fabric-setup..` was created on mac or ubuntu, remove it and commit on that machine.

Comment: No @ElpieKay. I am working only with windows. Updating the question

Comment: Try `git mv $oldname $newname && git commit`

Answer (score 0):

You could try (even in a simple CMD Windows shell session) a `git rm fabric-setup*`, followed by a git restore -s master fabric-setup
(using the new (experimental for now) command [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore), with Git 2.23)

That would remove both files, restore the good one: you can then add, commit and push.